# Calculating pixel area in region using ESA WorldCover 10 m v100 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using the 'ESA WorldCover 10m v100' dataset in Google Earth Engine and I am trying to calculate the area that each land cover classification covers in a region I specify. However, I don't know how to extract that band information from the dataset.

I only have the following code so far (since all attempts to do this have failed):

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v100").first();

var visualization = {
  bands: ['Map'],
};

Map.centerObject(area);

Map.addLayer(dataset.clip(area), visualization, "Landcover");
```

Comment: look into `Area Calculation by Class` section here https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/06/19/calculating-area-gee/

Comment: Thank you Aman! I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be by using [groupReducers](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_grouping)

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v100").first();

var areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(
      dataset)

var areas = areaImage.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'landcover_class',
    }),
    geometry: area,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13
    });
```

as referenced [here](https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/06/19/calculating-area-gee/)